# How to send a message to facebook account in my web site?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I have a web site that the user log in with his facebook account, Is there any way I can send to one of his friends a facebook message?

1. Is it possible to send a message from the user outbox?
2. Can I send a message from an account/other facebook entity I will create?
3. what else I can do to make some notification to the user's friend ?

Comment: Take a look at the [Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/). It's easy to understand and there are examples in popular programming languages. I think your goals can be achieved that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their is no API available for sending messages.  You can't message a user's friends.  Even if you could, you would get shut down immediately for spam.  You also can't get the email addresses of the users friends to spam them that way.

The closest thing you could do is use the [Requests dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) to send requests to a users friend, but the user would have control over what friends he wants to spam.